# Maxima of function in R

Tags: r

```
Y = 20*(1-EXP(-(10*(1-EXP(-X/400)))/5))* Premium - X
```

I want to maximize Y. At what value of X the value of Y will be maximized.
I need to write a function for this.

Sample Data

```
 id     premium     Y   X
110936  3300       NA   NA
41492   18000      NA   NA
31300   3300       NA   NA
19415   9600       NA   NA
99379   9600       NA   NA
```

Comment: Did you try something you can show ? Actually we have no idea if you tried something and can't gauge your knowledge level from that to write a comprehensive answer.

Comment: In Excel we use solver to maximize one column by changing a value of other column. We want to automate the same in R.

Answer (score 1):

Define your function in R, then use `optimize` to find its minimizer. Because you're looking for the maximum, you need to negate the output of your function definition.
You didn't specify how `Premium` fits into your optimization task, so I'm just going to assume that it's a fixed value:

```
f <- function(x)
{
  Premium <- 3300
  y <- 20*(1-exp(-(10*(1-exp(-x/400)))/5))* Premium - x
  -y  ## Negate the output, because we want to find the maximum
}
```

For univariate functions like yours, you would use `optimize`. For multivariate function (e.g., if you wanted to optimize over both `x` and `Premium`), you would use `optim`. You can do `?optimize` and `?optim` in R to read more about each function.

`optimize` takes a function and the interval over which to minimize:

```
optimize(f, c(0,1e6) )
# $minimum
# [1] 1536.798

# $objective
# [1] -55139.53
```